# Undesired bottom margin in (standard) 1080p layout template for a Windows Phone 8.1 app

Tags: xaml, layout, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

When I run my Windows Phone 8 app on the 8.1 1080 emulator, there's a black bottom margin on all its pages (interestingly, it actually doesn't appear when I'm viewing any of these pages in the Design view).

Initially, I thought it may be as a result of my custom laid-out PhoneApplicationPage. So, I decided to create a new PhoneApplicationPage and not make any changes i.e. Visual Studio's auto-generated Portrait PhoneApplicationPage. This is its xaml:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="App.Views._1080p"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Red">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,0">
        <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The only change I've made is add a red Background property for the Grid just to better highlight the problem.

I've not made any changes to the code-behind.

Unfortunately, the problem persisted:

[image]

If I add an App Bar to the xaml, the problem becomes exacerbated.

This is the App Bar's xaml:

```
<!-- APP BAR -->
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar 
        x:Name="appBar"
        IsVisible="True" 
        IsMenuEnabled="True" 
        Mode="Default" 
        Opacity="1" >
        <!-- APP BAR ICONS -->
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton 
            IconUri="a" 
            Text="Search"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image]

Any idea what's going on? And what I need to change to fix this problem? Any guidance would be much appreciated. I should add the problem does happen when running the app on a 1080p device too (i.e. not only a problem on the emulator).

Comment: So is that a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app or a Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight app? Either way, this is not showing on my 1080p device.

Comment: A Windows 8.0 Silverlight app.

Comment: I meant Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight app.

Comment: Is the emulator your running 8.1? it could be the emulator making redundencies for the new on screen buttons?

Comment: Yep it is, but as I mentioned this is happening on a 8.1 1080p device too (and not just on an 8.1 emulator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the explanation: on Windows Phone 8.1, the ApplicationBar's height is not fixed anymore, it depends on the device screen size. In order to not break existing 8.0 apps layouts, they added that black bar.

The height of this black bar is 12px (height of the 8.0 AppBar - 8.1 AppBar).

To remove it, you'll have to migrate the app to Windows Phone 8.1.

Comment: Thanks very much Olivier for the enlightenment. Will try this out. One question though - unless I've misunderstood, the height of the 8.1 AppBar is actually 12 pixels longer than 8.0's AppBar?

Comment: Yes, on 1080p devices running Windows Phone 8.1, the ApplicationBar is higher by 12px.

Comment: Okay so setting the ApplicationBar's opacity to 0.99 doesn't seem to have made any difference. I'd also rather not migrate the app to WP 8.1, because I want to keep it compatible with Windows Phone 8.0.

Comment: Ah crap. Well that sucks. I mean come on Microsoft.